# Deploy ReactJS on IIS within subfolder

Tags: reactjs, iis

I have a production build of ReactJS app. I want to deploy it on IIS server.
Example: 192.168.1.1/myreactapp

I want to access to the reactapp in the above url but it returns blank page.

If I put the physical path to the build folder, it opens the ReactApp but on 192.168.1.1 instead.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis Get yourself familiar with IIS concepts first. People usually deploy a web app at the root of a site, but if you prefer other options you need further changes.

Comment: This is related to the path of your deployment. If you want to access reactapp through 192.168.1.1/myreactapp, you can try to use [url rewrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is add homepage:"" in the package.json. Eg: homepage:"php/hello"
Then npm build the app and copy the contents of the build folder to php/hello directory. The web can then be accessed.